# Running sh script on Lubuntu on startup

Tags: lubuntu, cron, autostart, sh, autorun

Running lubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE

So, I need to run a simple SH script inside terminal session on startup after login, but I'm struggling to get it running.

I've tried: rc.local trick, /.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart trick, crontab trick, creating a service and enabling it with `systemctl enable` and adding it to autostart via built-in tool "Default applications for LXSession" but none of them bring terminal window up and run my script when I've logged into PC.

The commands I've tried to run in these tricks: `sh /path/to/script/file.sh`, `/bin/sh /path/to/script/file.sh`, `lxterminal -e sh /path/to/script/file.sh`

The system is fresh install of latest distro available on Lubuntu website, it has nothing in it. What script does is bring up Chromium window and echo some stuff to terminal periodically.

upd: script is:

```
chromium google.com --kiosk
while [ true ]
do
  echo Quit this terminal to kill chromium
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe sharing the script would help?

Comment: @DKBose edited question according your request. As I said earlier, this script is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a system user unit file.
This will be located at:

```
/home/<user>/.config/systemd/user/<name>.service
```

It is created like a normal unit file.
You enable it by:

```
systemctl --user start <name>
```

This will start the service at login.